# How can i use query_posts() in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to use [`query_posts()`<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function of wordpress. But how can i use it, I am new to wordpress. Basically want to select record by `post_title` name

```
$titleName = "My Post title name";

query_posts("post_title=".$titleName);

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
     echo the_title();
endwhile;
```

Is the above syntax correct or am missing something?

Comment: Always check [the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). What's happening that you're not expecting?

Comment: Are you getting any error or why are you wondering if the syntax is not correct?

Comment: @hakre..title is not printing

Comment: Try to use like query. query_posts("post_title = %$titleName%"); And keep your title small first to check wheather it is working or something else is wrong.

Comment: @riky..but $titleName is my variable name how can i add % sign before and after

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Wordpress' source code - what a great way to spend a Saturday night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an exact answer but its an alternate.
If you can't get it done by post name, You can get it by it's slug.

Show Post/Page by Slug

Display post by slug:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'name=about-my-life' );
```

Display page by slug:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=contact' );
```